# Dlang byLineCopy skipping lines

Tags: d

I have the following D program that is supposed to group input lines into groups of size 3.

```
import std.stdio;
import std.range;
import std.array;

void main()
{
  while (!stdin.eof) {
    auto currentBlock = array(take(stdin.byLineCopy, 3));

    foreach (i, e; currentBlock) {
      writefln("%d) %s", i, e);
    }
  }
}
```

and given the following input

```
Mercury
Venus
Earth
Mars
Jupiter
Saturn
Uranus
Neptune
Pluto
```

it produces the output.

```
0) Mercury
1) Venus
2) Earth
0) Jupiter
1) Saturn
2) Uranus
0) Pluto
```

skipping the line at the border on each iteration (Mars and Neptune are not in the output). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: hm seems like a bug in the take function to me. If you want some other function in the meantime to achieve the same thing, use `.chunks(3)` which returns a range of 3 length ranges

Comment: @WebFreak001 `chunks` is not working for me. It seems `byLineCopy` returns an `InputRange` and `chunks` expects a `ForwardRange`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`stdin.byLineCopy` [calls](https://github.com/dlang/phobos/blob/722683b65186a46a6f9977e15810ee766b257879/std/stdio.d#L2032) `popFront`, meaning that repeated calls to this on the same input stream will 'skip' elements. Try creating a `byLineCopy` range only once at the start:

```
void main()
{
    auto r = stdin.byLineCopy;
    while (!r.empty) {
        foreach (i, e; r.take(3).enumerate) {
          writefln("%d) %s", i, e);
        }
    }
}
```

You don't need to check for `eof`, as `byLineCopy` should handle that.

Comment: This solution has the behaviour I want. Isn't this a bug in `byLineCopy`?

Comment: I would not expect creating a range to mutate the source. The range 'API' says that we should call `front`, then `popFront`. However, this doesn't quite work for `stdin`, where you have to advance it in order to access `front` the first time, meaning we need an initial `popFront` to get things going. You could call it a bug, I call it an unfortunate reality :)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want [`std.range.chunks`](https://dlang.org/phobos/std_range.html#.chunks), combined with [`std.range.enumerate`](https://dlang.org/phobos/std_range.html#.enumerate) to preserve the indices:

```
void main()
{
    foreach (i, chunk; stdin.byLineCopy.array.chunks(3).enumerate) {
      writefln("%s", chunk);
    }
}
```

Note that `.array` is needed as `chunks` requires a `ForwardRange` while `stdin.byLineCopy` is an `InputRange`.

Comment: Your solution works. But, I would like to avoid the overhead of keeping the entire input in an array  (I believe this is what `.array` does) when I only need a small portion of it in memory at a time. This is one of the reasons why I used `take` instead of `chunks` in the first place.

Comment: I see. I think I've provided a better answer now. I'll delete this one if it doesn't add any value.